# Copying columns and formats on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have made significant changes in the code and now it takes about 20~40 seconds to process each worksheet. This will conditionally copy column based on the column headers in sheet2 that match to the ones in sheet3.

Here is the main module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub projectionTemplateFormat()

    Dim t1 As Double, t2 As Double

    xlSpeed True

        t1 = Timer
        mainProcess
        t2 = Timer

    xlSpeed False

    MsgBox "Duration: " & t2 - t1 & " seconds"

End Sub

Private Sub mainProcess()

    Const SPACE_DELIM   As String = " "

    Dim wsIndex             As Worksheet
    Dim wsImport            As Worksheet    'Raw
    Dim wsFinal             As Worksheet

    Dim indexHeaderCol      As Range
    Dim msg                 As String

    Dim importHeaderRng     As Range
    Dim importColRng        As Range
    Dim importHeaderFound   As Variant
    Dim importLastRow       As Long

    Dim finalHeaderRng      As Range
    Dim finalColRng         As Range
    Dim finalHeaderRow      As Variant
    Dim finalHeaderFound    As Variant
    Dim header              As Variant      'Each item in the FOR loop
    Dim lastRow As Long  'Manual Headers based on the number of rows in the raw data
    Dim rngs As Range


    Set wsIndex = aIndex    'This is the Code Name; top-left pane: aIndex (Index)
    Set wsImport = bImport  'Direct reference to Code Name: bImport.Range("A1")
    Set wsFinal = cFinal    'Reference using Sheets collection: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
    Set rngs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells


    lastRow = rngs.Find(What:="*", After:=rngs.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    wsFinal.Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H2").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AC2:AC" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H3").Value
    wsFinal.Range("X2:X" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H4").Value
    wsFinal.Range("Y2:Y" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H5").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AE2:AE" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H6").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AF2:AF" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H7").Value
    wsFinal.Range("AD2:AD" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H8").Value
    wsFinal.Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H9").Value




    With wsImport.UsedRange
        Set importHeaderRng = .Rows(1)      'Import - Headers
        importLastRow = .Rows.Count         'Import - Total Rows
    End With

    With wsFinal.UsedRange
        finalHeaderRow = .Rows(1)           'Final - Headers (as Array)
        Set finalHeaderRng = .Rows(1)       'Final - Headers (as Range)
    End With


    With wsIndex.UsedRange  'Transpose col 3 from Index (without the header), as column names in Import
        Set indexHeaderCol = .Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
        wsImport.Range(wsImport.Cells(1, 1), wsImport.Cells(1, .Rows.Count - 1)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(indexHeaderCol)
    End With


    If Len(bImport.Cells(1, 1).Value2) > 0 Then 'if Import sheet is not empty (1,1)

        With Application

            For Each header In finalHeaderRow   'Loop through all headers in Final

                If Len(Trim(header)) > 0 Then   'If the Final heade is not empty

                    importHeaderFound = .Match(header, importHeaderRng, 0)          'Find header in Import sheet

                    If IsError(importHeaderFound) Then
                        msg = msg & vbLf & header & SPACE_DELIM & wsImport.Name     'Import doesn't have current header
                    Else

                        finalHeaderFound = .Match(header, finalHeaderRng, 0)        'Find header in Final sheet

                        If IsError(finalHeaderFound) Then
                            msg = msg & vbLf & header & SPACE_DELIM & wsFinal.Name  'Import doesn't have current header
                        Else

                            With wsImport
                                Set importColRng = .UsedRange.Columns(importHeaderFound).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                            End With

                            With wsFinal
                                Set finalColRng = .Range(.Cells(2, finalHeaderFound), .Cells(importLastRow, finalHeaderFound))
                                finalColRng.Value2 = vbNullString                   'Delete previous values (entire column)
                            End With


                            finalColRng.Value2 = importColRng.Value2             'Copy Import data in Final columns

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next header
        End With




        allUpper wsFinal

                Dim i As Long
       For i = 2 To lastRow

          If IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value) And Not IsEmpty(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value) Then
            With wsFinal
                .Cells(i, "Q").Value = Year(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value)
            End With

          End If
       Next i



       Dim j As Long
          For j = 2 To lastRow

          If IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value) And Not IsEmpty(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value) Then
            With wsFinal
                .Cells(j, "R").Value = Year(wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value)
            End With

          End If

       Next j

          wsFinal.Columns("G").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("I").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("R").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("Q").NumberFormat = "@"
          wsFinal.Columns("T").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("W").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("V").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("AC").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
          wsFinal.Columns("N").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AM").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AN").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
          wsFinal.Columns("AO").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"



        'wsFinal.UsedRange.AutoFilter
        applyFormat wsFinal.Range(wsFinal.Cells(1, 1), wsFinal.Cells(importLastRow, wsFinal.UsedRange.Columns.Count))




    Dim ws As Worksheet
       For Each ws In Worksheets
       ws.Select
       ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
    Next ws

    Else
        MsgBox "Missing raw data (Sheet 2 - 'Import')", vbInformation, "   Missing Raw Data"
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub applyFormat(ByRef rng As Range)
    With rng
        '.ClearFormats

        With .Font
            .Name = "Georgia"
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 225)
        End With
        .Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
        With .Rows(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlDot  'xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With


    End With



    refit rng
End Sub

Private Sub allUpper(ByRef sh As Worksheet)
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.UsedRange) > 0 Then
        arr = sh.UsedRange  'one interaction with the sheet
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)         'each "row"
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)     'each "col"
                arr(i, j) = UCase(RTrim(Replace(arr(i, j), Chr(10), vbNullString)))
            Next
        Next
        sh.UsedRange = arr  'second interaction with the sheet
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub allImportTrim()
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = bImport

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.UsedRange) > 0 Then
        arr = sh.UsedRange  'one interaction with the sheet
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)         'each "row"
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)     'each "col"
                arr(i, j) = RTrim(Replace(arr(i, j), Chr(10), vbNullString))
            Next
        Next
        sh.UsedRange = arr  'second interaction with the sheet
    End If
    refit sh.UsedRange
End Sub

Private Sub refit(ByRef rng As Range)
    With rng
        .WrapText = False
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        '.Columns.AutoFit
        '.Rows.AutoFit
        .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

And a separate module that has minor functions and procedures:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearAll()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2:H11").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2:A100").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Sheets(2).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub transpose2()
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Range("A1").ClearOutline
End Sub

 Sub FormatasDatex()

    'Format to Date for any headers that contain "DATE" on Sheet3
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    Set wsh = Worksheets(3)
        Set aCell = wsh.Rows(1).Find(What:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            wsh.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

            lastRow = wsh.Range(Split(wsh.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
            wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To lastRow
                With wsh.Range(Split(wsh.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
                End With
            Next i

            wsh.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = wsh.Rows(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    wsh.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"

                    lastRow = wsh.Range(Split(wsh.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                    wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    For i = 2 To lastRow
                        wsh.Range(Split(wsh.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        wsh.Range(Split(wsh.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                    Next i
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
 End Sub

Sub GetRaw()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    'Set source workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<~~ You might want to use ThisWorkbook instead

    'Open the target workbook
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

    If vFile = False Then Exit Sub

    'Set targetworkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
    wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wb.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub





Public Sub xlSpeed(Optional ByVal optimize As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        If optimize Then
            If .Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Else
            If .Calculation <> xlCalculationAutomatic Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End If
        If .DisplayAlerts <> Not optimize Then .DisplayAlerts = Not optimize
        'If .DisplayStatusBar <> Not optimize Then .DisplayStatusBar = Not optimize
        'If .EnableAnimations <> Not optimize Then .EnableAnimations = Not optimize
        If .EnableEvents <> Not optimize Then .EnableEvents = Not optimize
        If .ScreenUpdating <> Not optimize Then .ScreenUpdating = Not optimize
    End With
    xlSheetsSpeed , optimize
End Sub

Private Sub xlSheetsSpeed(Optional ByVal paramSheet As Worksheet, Optional ByVal optimize As Boolean = True)
    If paramSheet Is Nothing Then
        For Each paramSheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            With paramSheet
                .DisplayPageBreaks = False
                .EnableCalculation = Not optimize
                '.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = Not optimize
                '.EnablePivotTable = Not optimize
            End With
        Next
    Else
        With paramSheet
            .DisplayPageBreaks = False
            .EnableCalculation = Not optimize
            '.EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = Not optimize
            '.EnablePivotTable = Not optimize
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub xlResetSettings()
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableAnimations = False
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        For Each sh In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            With sh
                .DisplayPageBreaks = False
                .EnableCalculation = True
                .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True
                .EnablePivotTable = True
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Does this follow best practices?

Answer (score 6):

This *looks* nice, but it's a proven waste of time.

> ```
> Dim wsIndex             As Worksheet
> Dim wsImport            As Worksheet    'Raw
> Dim wsFinal             As Worksheet
>
> Dim indexHeaderCol      As Range
> Dim msg                 As String
>
> Dim importHeaderRng     As Range
> Dim importColRng        As Range
> Dim importHeaderFound   As Variant
> Dim importLastRow       As Long
> ```

Let's say I want to rename `msg` to be a little more verbose and less abbreviated. Then I get this.

> ```
> Dim wsIndex             As Worksheet
> Dim wsImport            As Worksheet    'Raw
> Dim wsFinal             As Worksheet
>
> Dim indexHeaderCol      As Range
> Dim message                 As String
>
> Dim importHeaderRng     As Range
> Dim importColRng        As Range
> Dim importHeaderFound   As Variant
> Dim importLastRow       As Long
> ```

And now I'm wasting precious time on formatting that block, you know, instead of writing code. The code below is no less readable once you get accustomed to it.

```
Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
Dim wsImport As Worksheet    'Raw
Dim wsFinal As Worksheet

Dim indexHeaderCol As Range
Dim msg As String

Dim importHeaderRng As Range
Dim importColRng As Range
Dim importHeaderFound As Variant
Dim importLastRow As Long
```

I **do** like your use of vertical white space though. It breaks your declaration up into logical chunks. There is a problem with that though. Declaring all of your variables at the top of the procedure adds space in between the declaration of a variable and it's use. It's proven that increasing the number of lines between a variable's declaration and it's end of life decreases code quality. [I recommend you pick up a copy of Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/). Steve McConnell covers this is some detail.

So, try to declare your variables just before using them.

```
Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
Set wsIndex = aIndex    'This is the Code Name; top-left pane: aIndex (Index)
```

Once you get accustomed to this, you can begin to (at least partially) gauge the quality of a routine by looking at the distance between a variable's declaration and it's last use.

Speaking of, let's talk about that comment...

> ```
> Set wsIndex = aIndex    'This is the Code Name; top-left pane: aIndex (Index)
> ```

Where is `aIndex` defined? It's not defined in this Sub, which means you're using a global variable. Don't do that. Pass it in to the sub as an argument. Restrict it's scope. Global state is a nightmare once your code grows beyond anything trivial. Also, why not give these variables a reasonable name? If you need a comment to explain what a variable **is**, then you need to rename that variable.

This....

> ```
>  If Len(bImport.Cells(1, 1).Value2) > 0 Then 'if Import sheet is not empty (1,1)
> ```

This is reasonably complicated logic for a boolean check. Even though this is the *only* time may be using this logic, it is absolutely reasonable to extract it into a private boolean function; just to make the code readable.

```
Private Function IsSheetEmpty(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    IsSheetEmpty = (Len(ws.Cells(1, 1).Value2) > 0)
End Function
```

Then back up in your `If` statement...

```
If IsSheetEmpty(bImport) Then
```

There's no reason to Activate/Select all over the place here. You use variable reference elsewhere, there's no reason not to do it here too.

> ```
> Sub ClearAll()
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Range("H2:H11").Select
>     Selection.ClearContents
>     Range("A2:A100").Select
>     Selection.ClearContents
>     Selection.ClearFormats
>     Sheets(2).Select
>     Cells.Select
>     Selection.ClearContents
>     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
>     Sheets(1).Select
>     Range("A2").Select
>     ActiveSheet.UsedRange
>     ThisWorkbook.Save
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> End Sub
> ```

Lastly, remove the commented out code. Commented out code is dead code, nothing but clutter. If you're afraid of losing it for some reason, then you're not using Version Control. Friend, you should be. You can do it [the hard way](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/vba-and-git/), if you can't install any third party libraries, or take advantage the [Source Control library in Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Source-Control-API) *(Disclaimer, I'm one of the owners of the project)*. There is zero excuse not to be using some sort of source control.

---

This was by no means a thorough review. I didn't have a lot of time. Hopefully someone else comes by with a fine tooth comb.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! I'll have to take blame where the blame is due: most of your feedback is on MY bad behavior: 1. horizontal alignment is mine; I do it for faster visual references and maintainability, but I'll adapt to anything that improves performance 2. "aIndex" is the worksheet code name, similar to the default "Sheet1". It replaces the normal WorkSheets(1), and it's the only global I usually use 3. "complicated logic for a boolean check" - point taken 4. all comments are mine, to explain everything the code does for learning purposes. I usually use self-documenting variable names

Comment: I think you'd really benefit from the book I linked to. You could pick one up used for about $30. It has lots of VB examples in it.

Answer (score 4):

## Naming.

Did you notice, *every single identifier* in the VBA standard library (or any other library you might reference, for that matter) uses `PascalCase`? Following standard conventions make your code easier to read, and therefore to maintain.

Keep `camelCase` for locals and parameters.  `YELLCASE` or `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` is a commonly used convention for constants, so I wouldn't change that.

I'm not sure what casing this is using:

```
Sub FormatasDatex()
```

CamelCase would be `FormatAsDateX`, but that "X" only makes me want to dig into the implementation to see what it stands for... and it turns out it just seems an arbitrary suffix that tells me nothing about the date format - actually, the date format is much less relevant than the fact that the procedure is an extremely specialized piece of code that formats some very specific cells on a very specific worksheet.

That's very, very frail: if a worksheet is ever inserted anywhere before the 3rd sheet, you have a bug.

I need to say something about this prefixing pattern:

```
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
```

```
Set wsIndex = aIndex
Set wsImport = bImport
Set wsFinal = cFinal
```

`aCell` and `bCell` aren't any better than `cell1` and `cell2` (which are just as awfully meaningless) - if `aCell` is a search result, then why not call it `searchResult`? Prefixes `a`, `b` and `c` seem completely arbitrary - and if they denote a sequence of some sort, that sequence seems outside the scope of the procedure and as such, doesn't belong there.

---

#### DoSomething

Procedures *do something*. Their names should always start with a verb that describes that. If the only name you can think of is vague and doesn't really describe what's going on, then chances are that you're looking at a procedure that's doing too many things. But I'll get back to that.

A procedure called `xlSpeed` doesn't say anything about what it's doing. Looking at its implementation and usage makes me wonder why it's not just called `ToggleWaitMode` with an `Optional wait As Boolean = True` parameter. Seeing that `DisplayPageBreaks = False` has no toggle state, makes me wonder... do page breaks really make that much of a difference when `ScreenUpdating` is disabled?

You know how property getters have this `Property Get` keyword in them, and *return the property value*? Any procedure that starts with `Get`, *that doesn't return anything*, has a horrible name. I'm completely confused with what `GetRaw` is supposed to be doing. My only clue is this comment:

```
Dim wsImport            As Worksheet    'Raw
```

...which only makes sense after I've seen that `GetRaw` procedure and went WTF over it.

---

This is overly verbose:

```
If optimize Then
    If .Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Else
    If .Calculation <> xlCalculationAutomatic Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If
```

How about this?

```
.Calculation = IIf(optimize, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
```

Avoid double negatives in conditionals:

```
If .ScreenUpdating <> Not optimize Then .ScreenUpdating = Not optimize
```

"If screen updating **is not *not*** then". What's the cost of reassigning the same value, versus that of accessing it twice? Get rid of that confusing wording, and *Keep It Simple, Stupid*:

```
.ScreenUpdating = Not optimize
```

---

## Object Model Usage

The Microsoft Excel object model exposes a `Worksheets` and a `Sheets` collection - if your code can't deal with *chart sheets*, then stick to the `Worksheets` collection.

As far as best practices go, this isn't it. Your intention is to reference a very *specific* worksheet, with very specific content. Referring to worksheets by their index makes the whole thing fall apart, the minute a user decides he prefers having the worksheets sorted by name, and starts rearranging the order of things.

All worksheets have a `Name` property, but the user can change that as well. The single safest way to refer to a specific worksheet, is using its `CodeName`. And best of all, that *code name* happens to be a workbook-scoped object reference to the `Worksheet` object you're after.

If I understand correctly, you have a global-scope reference to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")` with `cFinal`, that you copy to `wsFinal`, ...when the worksheet in question might have *code name* `Sheet23`. Why not give the special sheet code name `FinalSheet`, and ditch all the global variables and their copies?

#### Consistency.

What's the difference between this:

```
Set rngs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells
```

And that?

```
wsFinal.Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Value = Sheets(1).Range("H2").Value
```

Nevermind that you should be using the `Worksheets` collection here - my question is, *why is it fully qualified in one place, and implicitly qualified in the other?*

---

## Parameterize.

Take this short little procedure as an example:

```
Sub transpose2()
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Range("A1").ClearOutline
End Sub
```

Ignoring the fact that it's implicitly `Public` (why is it even in another module? who else is calling it?) and its poor name (what happened to `transpose1`?), ...and that `Range("A1")` is implicitly referring to the active sheet (danger!), ...what was I going to say here?

Ah, yes. Parameters. Consider:

```
Public Sub CopyPasteSpecialTranspose(ByVal source As Range, ByVal destination As Range)
    source.Copy
    destination.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This procedure says what it does, *and does what it says*. **Nothing more**. Clearing outlines on the active sheet is a rather surprising side-effect of transposing a range... especially if it just so happens that the active sheet isn't one of the worksheets involved in the copy+paste operation.

By passing in `source` and `destination` parameters, you've now written *reusable code*.

---

## S.R.P.

Single. Responsibility. Principle. Do one thing, do it well. `MainProcess` is way too long to be doing that. *Extract methods*, my friend. Break that monster down into pieces that fit a screen, and have a name that says exactly what's going on.

Pass your "dependencies" as parameters, avoid implicit references to active sheet (or to anything for that matter - be explicit!), and regroup methods logically - don't send a handful of procedures into another module just for the heck of it!

A code module should read and unfold like a story: at the top you have a high *level of abstraction* with abstract concepts (*CopySourceData*, *FormatOutputSheet*, etc.), followed by more and more specialized methods with a lower and lower level of abstraction, that culminate with the knowledge of all the specific range addresses and other implementation details: if you want to know *what* the code does, you read the top of the module; when you want to know *how* it does it, you read the bottom.

I'd recommend [Robert C. Martin's *Clean Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) for more details about abstraction levels, and many, many other things. The code samples are Java, but the concepts are pretty much language-agnostic.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Very methodical and consistent - I'm sure it's a reflection of your work. You made some excellent points (some of them are for me, but not all). I have the file he's working on and went over this entire functionality to fix some bugs, and improve performance - it's now quite decent at about 4 seconds for 50K records (down from 20-30 sec), but I was in a bit of a hurry. I'll post the code bellow as an answer - feel free to highlight any improvements (I'll also get the book) but for now I'll take anything I can get

Comment: @paulbica thanks! make sure your answer actually reviews OP's code (code-dump answers are frowned upon on this site) - if you pretty much rewrote it and would like it reviewed, you can always post your own question (I believe the [tag:rags-to-riches] community tag might be applicable there)

Comment: Thanks - I was almost ready to post the full code when I saw your reply. I'll start another thread for it

Answer (score 2):

All points made by the previous reviews are great.

I'd emphasize the divide-and-conquer strategy of breaking up large functions into individual items designed for a distinct purpose. It will allow for reusability, reduced complexity, and ease of maintenance on the long run

Also, consistency in naming conventions

In reference to some of @Mat's points:

```
Set wsIndex = aIndex
Set wsImport = bImport
Set wsFinal = cFinal
```

[image: CodeNames of the workbooks]

.

- This is an excellent suggestion:

`.Calculation = IIf(optimize, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)`

> Avoid double negatives in conditionals

This line:

```
If .ScreenUpdating <> Not optimize Then .ScreenUpdating = Not optimize
```

started out as this:

```
.ScreenUpdating = Not optimize
```

and I changed it to avoid updating if it's not needed

- I'm stingy with names, like "msg". But **CopySourceData, FormatOutputSheet** is the self documenting cod I want to do (when I'm not pressured by deadlines)